# Derefencing an iterator pointing to a custom class

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, iterator

I have a set of class objects (Fighter) that I'm iterating through, occasionally calling that class's member functions. It seems like I'm incorrectly dereferencing my iterator when I try to call a member function of the object the iterator is pointing to.

```
std::cout << (*iter)->getFrame(text);
```

I'm getting the following compiler error:

> error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'const Fighter'

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `->` operator directly on `iter`. If you want to dereference first, you'd use the `.` operator: `(*iter).getFrame(text);`

```
std::cout << iter->getFrame(text);
```

or

```
std::cout << (*iter).getFrame(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your container clearly does not contain a pointer type as its element type.  Dereferencing an iterator gives you a reference to an element in the container, eg:

```
container::value_type &element = *iter;
```

If the element type is not a pointer, and the type does not overload the `->` operator (for instance, smart pointer types typically do), then you can't use the `->` operator to access the element's members:

```
element->getFrame(text); // error!
```

You need to use the `.` operator instead:

```
element.getFrame(text); // OK!
```

Putting it back into context, you end up with this:

```
std::cout << (*iter).getFrame(text); // OK!
```

The alternative is to use the `->` operator on the iterator itself, which dereferences the iterator for you so you can access the element's members in the same expression:

```
std::cout << iter->getFrame(text); // OK!
```